# Override large medium and small button labels, material-ui

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to style Button only using overrides in the theme. I can use sizeLarge and sizeSmall to target the corresponding buttons, but there is no sizeMedium. Targeting root gets overwritten by MuiButton-label and targeting label overwrites sizeSmall and sizeLarge.

Here's the code

```js
<Button color="primary" variant="contained" size="large">
  Button Name - Large
</Button>
<Button color="primary" variant="contained">
  Button Name - Medium
</Button>
<Button color="primary" variant="contained" size="small">
  Button Name - Small
</Button>
```

and theme.js

```js
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import "typeface-poppins";
import "typeface-open-sans";

export const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        // Style sheet name ⚛️
        MuiButton: {
            // Name of the rule
            // gets overwritten by label styles
            // if label, overwrites below styles
            root: {
                // Some CSS
                font: "normal normal 700 0.875rem/1.6875rem Open Sans",
                color: "green",
            },
            sizeLarge: {
                // Some CSS
                font: "normal normal 700 0.9375rem/1.6875rem Open Sans",
            },
            sizeSmall: {
                font: "normal normal 700 0.8125rem/1.6875rem Open Sans",
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still reference the `label` rule name, but for `root`, specify that the CSS rules are not to be applied to `.MuiButton-sizeLarge` & `.MuiButton-sizeSmall`

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      root: {                
        "&:not($sizeLarge):not($sizeSmall) $label": {
          font: "normal normal 700 0.875rem/1.6875rem Open Sans",
          color: "green"
        }
      },
      sizeLarge: {
        "& $label": {
          font: "normal normal 700 0.9375rem/1.6875rem Open Sans",
        }
      },
      sizeSmall: {
        "& $label": {
          font: "normal normal 700 0.8125rem/1.6875rem Open Sans"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

function App () {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button color="primary" variant="contained" size="large">
        Button Name - Large
      </Button>
      <Button color="primary" variant="contained">
        Button Name - Medium
      </Button>
      <Button color="primary" variant="contained" size="small">
        Button Name - Small
      </Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <script type="text/babel">
    const { createMuiTheme, Button, ThemeProvider } = MaterialUI;
  </script>
</body>
```